# How to define var outside if statement and use it outside

Tags: swift

```
var firstname: [String] = []
var year = Int.random(in: 1900 ... 2020)
if (1900 ..< 1910).contains(year){
    if (gender == "male"){
        firstname = _1900s_boysnames_uk.randomElement()
    }
}
```

Get error cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type '[String]' for firstname
How do i fix this?

Answer (score 6):

`firstname` variable is a type on `[String]` whitch means that is should contain an array of Strings.

On line `firstname = _1900s_boysnames_uk.randomElement()` you assign a value of `String` to the array of Strings.

To fix it you can change the line into `firstname.append(_1900s_boysnames_uk.randomElement())`.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error, because the array `_1900s_boysnames_uk` might be empty, so the returned value from the `randomElement()` also might be `nil`, for that we consider the returned value as `optional`

you can add ? int your first line, which means that the array can contain `nil` values, but it's not the better way

```
var firstname: [String?] = []
```

or you can use this syntax inside your if condition

```
if let firstname = _1900s_boysnames_uk.randomElement() {
    firstname.append(firstname)
}
```

---

### Addition, please

```
var firstname: [String] = []
```

It means that the variable "firstname" will contain a list of names

and to to add a new name to the list, you will use "append" like:

```
firstname.append(_1900s_boysnames_uk.randomElement())
```

If you want to assign only a name to it, use:

```
var firstname: String
```

> the recommendation in Swift is to use a camel case naming convention when naming variables. If you’re not aware of camel case, it is a naming convention that uses a lowercase letter for the first word in a variable name followed by a capital letter for each subsequent word.